# Attaching an Event Handler to only one content type or list

Tags: event-handlers, content-type

Could someone help and explain how I can attach an event handler on a custom content type or a particular list?

Currently, when I deploy my event handler as a feature and activate the feature, it is applied to all the lists.

Thanks,

Matrich

Answer (score 2):

Use the [Receivers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms431081.aspx) element in the element manifest with `ListTemplateId` for lists or add the `Receivers` element as a sub element to the `XmlDocument` element in the Content Type ([read more here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff713708%28office.12%29.aspx))

Answer (score 0):

adding event receiver to document library /list programatically. here i am mentioning for Document Library.

```
     SPDocumentLibrary docLib = web.Lists.TryGetList("Temp Resources") as SPDocumentLibrary;
        docLib.EnableVersioning = true;
        docLib.EnableMinorVersions = false;
        docLib.Update();
        if (docLib != null)
        {
            docLib.EventReceivers.Add(SPEventReceiverType.ItemUpdating, Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().FullName, "Event Receiver Class Name");
            docLib.EventReceivers.Add(SPEventReceiverType.WorkflowCompleted, Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().FullName, "Event Receiver Class Name");
        }
```